# How can I print text immediately without waiting for a newline in Perl?

Tags: perl, printing, newline

I have a computationally expensive task in perl, and would like to inform the user that computation is ongoing by printing out a period after each portion of the computation is completed. Unfortunately, until I print a "\n", none of my periods are printed. How can I address this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to set autoflush for STDOUT. Example:

```
use IO::Handle;
STDOUT->autoflush(1);
foreach (1..20) {
  print '.';
  sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: @Hans Please do not link to unauthorized copies of books.

Comment: See http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003135 and http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003135 .

Comment: Sorry, it just popped up when I searched the web. Now removed the link.

Answer (score 7):

set `$|=1` before you start printing.  Eg.

```
perl -e ' $|=1; foreach (1..10) { print "$_ "; sleep(1); }'
```

Comment: @ar, `STDOUT->autoflush(1)` is the same thing as `$|=1` except `$|=1`, is global and `STDOUT->autoflush(1)` is specific to one handle.

Comment: Except you have to do a `use IO::Handle`.  Not that `IO::Handle` hasn't been a standard module for eons, but ... yeah. :(`

Answer (score 4):

An excellent article you should read: [Suffering from Buffering?](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html)

Answer (score 2):

See the FAQ [How do I flush/unbuffer an output filehandle? Why must I do this?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-flush/unbuffer-an-output-filehandle%3f--Why-must-I-do-this%3f)  and note:

> Besides the `$|`  special variable, you can use [`binmode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) to give your filehandle a `:unix`  layer, which is unbuffered ...

For the general problem, you might want to look at [Time::Progress](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Time::Progress):

> `%b`
>
> `%B`
>
> progress bar which looks like:
>
> ```
> ##############......................
> ```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to put the line

```
STDOUT->autoflush(1);
```

before my line

```
print ".";
```

inside my existing loop. Didn't use the sleep for fear of slowing the things down even more.